# Charles with Android: SSL handshake with client failed: An unknown issue occurred processing the certificate (certificate_unknown)

Tags: android, ssl, https, charles-proxy

### My Environment

- Android 12 LG Velvet
- Charles 4.6.5
- MacOS Ventura 13.6.3
- My App (I want to see https traffic of this app with charles)
- I installed charles certificate in my phone
  [image]
- I configured charles ssl proxy
  [image]

### The Issue

I can not use https in `MyApp` (plus, all the android app except browsers)
[image]

### P.S.

I tested with browser (MS Edge for android).
I could access Internet.
I could see the traffic through charles and it was https. I can use browsers, but all other apps doesn't work. (youtube, play store doesn't work)

### Question

- Only browsers working fine. (when I remove the certificate, then browsers can not use https) how to make other apps (youtube, play store and "MyApp") to use Charles certificate?

Answer (score 1):

I found the missing piece!

https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/using-charles/ssl-certificates/

As of `Android N`, you need to add configuration to your app in order to have it trust the SSL certificates generated by `Charles SSL Proxying`. This means that you can only use `SSL Proxying` with apps that you control.

In order to configure your app to trust `Charles`, you need to add a `Network Security Configuration` File to your app. This file can override the system default, enabling your app to trust user installed `CA` certificates (e.g. the `Charles Root Certificate`). You can specify that this only applies in debug builds of your application, so that production builds use the default trust profile.

Add a file `res/xml/network_security_config.xml` to your app:

```
<network-security-config> 
  <debug-overrides> 
    <trust-anchors> 
      <!-- Trust user added CAs while debuggable only -->
      <certificates src="user" /> 
    </trust-anchors> 
  </debug-overrides> 
</network-security-config>
```

Then add a reference to this file in your app's manifest, as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ... >
    <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" ... >
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

So I need to

1. add above configuration
2. build the `debug build`